# How to find container of dynamically created button ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, webforms, mouseclick-event

I have a WebForm whose controls are created dynamically as they can vary in number. Each element is a Panel containing a TextBox, a DropDownList and a Button. 
Each control is given a unique ID and all the buttons have the same clickEvent. Inside the code of the clickEvent, I want to obtain the ID of the panel in which the presedButton belongs so I can access the chosen value from that Panel's DropDownList and the text from the TextBox. 
How can I do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var panelId = ((Button)sender).Parent.ID;

    }
```

Or you could get the controls directly

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var myTextbox = ((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
        var myDropDownlist = ((Button)sender.Parent.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>().FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

or by control ID:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var myTextbox = ((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.ID == "textboxID").SingleOrDefault();
        var myDropDownlist = ((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>().Where(x => x.ID == "dropdownlistID").SingleOrDefault();

    }
```